# gettimeofday difference not giving me a time range

Tags: c, time

I'm writing something basic in c that times how long it takes to execute a shell script.

I have

```
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
// code here

gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
// print end - start
```

I know that the timeval struct has tv_sec and tv_usec which I accounted for but even for scripts such as "sleep 3" I'm still getting 0 for this end - start difference. Any guesses as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this: [gettimeofday() should never be used to measure time](http://blog.habets.pp.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time)

Try `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` instead.

Comment: You are right: in serious soft developer must do only so. My method is only for easy things for self-use.

Answer (score 0):

Try for example this:

```
double dtime(){
    double t;
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    t = tv.tv_sec + ((double)tv.tv_usec)/1e6;
    return t;
}

…
double t0 = dtime();
…
printf("Time spend: %g seconds\n", dtime()-t0);
```